# Filter Creation Date By Time Range

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

[image]Im trying to filter my first two IF statement to only show the created_at records from 8 am to 10 am for todays current date, right now it just does the date, i need change date= date to created_at = '' however that would be done in a range. Here is my views.py. How do i add this to my IF statement ? Thanks

views.py

```
def Student_Progress(request, studentpsid):

    if request.method == "GET":

        date = datetime.date.today()
        # Calculates Points on Student Progress Page
        academic = K8Points.objects.values_list('academic', flat=True).filter(
            student_name_id=studentpsid).filter(date=date)
        behavior = K8Points.objects.values_list('behavior', flat=True).filter(
            student_name_id=studentpsid).filter(date=date)
        my_class_id = request.session['my_class_id']
        academic_total = 0
        behav_total = 0
        for score in academic:
            academic_total += int(score)
        for score in behavior:
            behav_total += int(score)
        grand_total = academic_total + behav_total
        counseling = Student.objects.values_list(
            'counseling_goal', flat=True).get(studentpsid=studentpsid)
        studentid = Student.objects.get(studentpsid=studentpsid)
        k8obj = K8Points.objects.filter(
            student_name_id=studentpsid, date=date).order_by('time_frame')
        # Checks To See If a Student Gets Morning Recess
        if grand_total >= 20 and K8Points.objects.filter(time_frame=1).filter(date=date) and K8Points.objects.filter(time_frame=2).filter(date=date) and K8Points.objects.filter(time_frame=3).filter(date=date):
            morning_recess = "YES"
            context = ({'studentid': studentid, 'date': date, 'counseling': counseling, 'grand_total': grand_total, 'academic_total': academic_total,
                        'behav_total': behav_total, 'k8obj': k8obj, 'my_class_id': my_class_id, 'morning_recess': morning_recess})
            return render(request, 'points/student_progress.html', context)
        if grand_total <= 20 and K8Points.objects.filter(time_frame=1) and K8Points.objects.filter(time_frame=2) and K8Points.objects.filter(time_frame=3).filter(date=date):
            morning_recess = "NO"
            context = ({'studentid': studentid, 'date': date, 'counseling': counseling, 'grand_total': grand_total, 'academic_total': academic_total,
                        'behav_total': behav_total, 'k8obj': k8obj, 'my_class_id': my_class_id, 'morning_recess': morning_recess})
            return render(request, 'points/student_progress.html', context)
        else:
            context = ({'studentid': studentid, 'date': date, 'counseling': counseling, 'grand_total': grand_total, 'academic_total': academic_total,
                        'behav_total': behav_total, 'k8obj': k8obj, 'my_class_id': my_class_id, })
            return render(request, 'points/student_progress.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class K8Points(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today()) 
    class_name = models.ForeignKey(TeacherClass, on_delete = models.PROTECT, default = "",)
    student_name = models.ForeignKey(Student,on_delete = models.CASCADE, default ="" ,) 
    week_of = models.IntegerField(default=weeknumber)
    day = models.CharField(max_length= 10, default = dayofweek)
    TIME_FRAME_CHOICES = [
        (None, 'PLEASE SELECT TIME FRAME'),  # THIS IS OPTIONAL
        (1, '(1.) 8:45AM - 9:00AM'),
        (2, '(2.) 9:00AM - 9:30AM'),
        (3, '(3.) 9:30AM - 10:00AM'),
        (4, '(4.) REC. I 10:00AM -10:10AM'),
        (5, '(5.) 10:10AM-10:40AM'),
        (6, '(6.) 10:40AM-11:10AM'),
        (7, '(7.) 11:10AM-11:40AM'),
        (8, '(8.) REC II LUNCH 11:40AM-12:20PM'),
        (9, '(9.) 12:20PM-12:50PM'),
        (10,'(10.) 12:50PM-1:20PM'),
        (11,'(11.) 1:20PM-1:50PM'),
        (12,'(12.) 1:50PM-2:20PM'),
        (13,'(13.) REC. III 2:20PM-2:30PM'),
    ]
    time_frame = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=TIME_FRAME_CHOICES,)
    behavior = models.IntegerField(default="", validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(5),
            MinValueValidator(1)
        ])
    academic = models.IntegerField(default="", validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(5),
            MinValueValidator(0)
        ] )
    total = models.IntegerField(default=0 )
    morning_recess= models.CharField(max_length= 3, blank = True ,default = "" )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for today day filter

```
today_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()

.filter(your_datetime_field__date = today_date)
```

for hour filter

```
.filter(your_datetime_field__hour__lte = 10).filter(your_datetime_field__hour__gte = 8)
```

Keep in mind that 10:59:59 will be in results of this query too. 
If you need only 8:00:00 - 9:59:59 use `lt` instead of `lte`

Comment: ```if grand_total >= 20 and K8Points.objects.filter(time_frame=1).filter(date=date).filter(created_at__hour__lte=13).filter(created_at__hour__gte=8) and K8Points.objects.filter(time_frame=2).filter(date=date).filter(created_at__hour__lte=13).filter(created_at__hour__gte=8) and K8Points.objects.filter(time_frame=3).filter(date=date).filter(created_at__hour__lte=13).filter(created_at__hour__gte=8):```

Comment: I guess it because you filter `filter(date=date)` instead of `filter(date__date=date)` as i wrote. If with this fix it still doesn't work, add your model class to question.

Comment: ``` today_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
        if grand_total >= 20 and K8Points.objects.filter(time_frame=1).filter(created_at__date = today_date).filter(created_at__hour__lt=13).filter(created_at__hour__gte=8) and K8Points.objects.filter(time_frame=2).filter(created_at__date = today_date).filter(created_at__hour__lte=13).filter(created_at__hour__gte=8) and K8Points.objects.filter(time_frame=3).filter(created_at__date = today_date).filter(created_at__hour__lte=13).filter(created_at__hour__gte=8):```

Comment: Still nothing, also star im new to django, is there a cleaner way i can write that if statement ?

Comment: Star the issue isnt the code you gave me, im looking at the database and its posting the wrong time in the created_at field however in the dev server its correct when it shows you the get and post time stamps.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand right what queryset means in "if" statement. If result of query is empty then "if" statement return False. You are using "and" in your "if" statement and one empty query result is enough to bring your whole "if" statement to False

Comment: Your queryset can be optimized like this `K8Points.objects.filter(time_frame__in = [1,2,3]).filter(created_at__date = today_date).filter(created_at__hour__lt=13).filter(created_at__hour__gte=8)` Check if this queryset return something, and if it is, move on with your `if grand_total >= 20`

Comment: No Star i understand completely but what I'm saying is the If statement is failing cause the timestamp in the database is wrong. 2020-01-13 17:22:14.253819  Thats what im getting, since im Eastern Time US, Shouldnt that hour be 12 ? Current timenow is 12:28PM

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205883/discussion-between-wearestardust-and-ray-zuchowski).